# How to render input fields in a custom page template page

Tags: 7, nodes, theming

Running into a development wall here. How does one render form/fields in a custom page?

*e.g.*

I've created a custom page called `page--node--add--article.tpl.php` (a custom page to style the editing of the article content type) though I cant render any individual input/forms as part of my overall site design.

All I can do is do  `<?php print render($page['content']); ?>` which loads the entire content and does not allow me to style between the different fields.

Objective: Split the article creation into two DIVs for a mobile theme that gives me a part one and then via jQuery fade (or slide) to the part 2.

Comment: I think you should use `hook_form_alter` for changing in form design.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize your form using [#prefix](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#prefix) and [#suffix](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#suffix) in [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). They will add wrapper HTML markup into your form and then you can customize them with your custom CSS and JS attached to the form.

Here is an example code:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, &$form_id){
    if($form_id == 'article_node_form'){
        $form['title']['#prefix'] = '<div id="group1">';
        // more fields here
        $form['body']['#suffix']  = '</div>';

        $form['field_1']['#prefix'] = '<div id="group2">';
        // more fields here
        $form['field_5']['#suffix'] = '</div>';

        // attach additional css/js to this form page for your customization
        $form['#attached']['css'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule'). '/mymodule.css';
        $form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule'). '/mymodule.js';     
    }   
}
```

You can also add additional HTML using [#markup](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#markup).

```
$form["unique_id"] = array(
    '#markup' => "<div>some html</div>"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`page--node--add--article.tpl.php` is for a page level template.

The template just the form, you'd be better to look into a form level template.

If you're just wanting to split the form into two divs, checkout the module:

### [field_group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group)

> Available group types:
>
> - Fieldsets
> - Horizontal tabs
> - Vertical tabs
> - Accordions
> - Divs
> - Multipage steps: (client side)

Answer (score 0):

Other than fields, if you want to arrange your nodes, views, comments, user data etc.. you can go for [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds).

**Advanced options**

- Exportables
- Add your own custom fields in the backend or in your code
- Add custom layouts in your theme (D7 only)
- Change labels, add styles or override field settings (semantic fields).
- Full integration with Views and Panels
- Extend the power of your layouts by installing Field Group
- Optimal performance with Object cache (D6) or Entity cache (D7) integration